# Concatenate string to create variable in jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to work on a template to manage some server information.
The code works the same way for prod or stage.

```
{%- for key_uber, value_uber in uber_dict|dictsort -%}
    {%- for env_item in ["stage" , "prod"] -%}
        {#SET UP OPERATION#}
        {%- if value_uber.environment.prod == false and value_uber.prod != [] -%}
            {%- set operation_type = 'create' -%}
        {%- elif value_uber.environment.prod != false and value_uber.prod != [] -%}
            {%- set operation_type = 'update' -%}
        {%- else -%}
            {%- set operation_type = 'cancel' -%}
        {%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
    {{- card_list.append(operation_type) -}}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Basically, what I would like to do is to replave the env_item for all the prod or stage.
Is it possible to concatenate or join variable to create a new variable?

**Clarification and examples**
So, let me try to add some clarification and some examples of the *uber_dict*

This is basic composition of the uber_dict:

```
{
  "app_1": {

    "criticality": "3 - Normal",
    "owner": [
      "owner1@nomail.com"
    ],
    "prod": [
      "server1",
      "server2"
    ],
    "stage": [
      "server3",
      "server4"
    ]
  },
  "app_2": {
    "criticality": "3 - Normal",
    "owner": [
      "owner2@nomail.com"
    ],
    "prod": [
      "server1"
    ],
    "stage": [
      "server5"
    ]
  }
 }
```

What I'm trying to do is to make the code of the template independent of the environment.
When I call *value_uber.environment.prod*, instead of having prod I can have *prod* or *stage*
For example:

value_uber.environment.prod --> value_uber.environment.env_item

Thanks

Comment: You have a lot of code, but it's not the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); what are you trying to do, demonstrated in the smallest example?

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was easier than I thought.

```
{%- for key_uber, value_uber in uber_dict|dictsort -%}
    {%- for env_item in ["stage" , "prod"] -%}
        {#SET UP OPERATION#}
        {%- if value_uber.environment[env_item] == false and value_uber[env_item] != [] -%}
            {%- set operation_type = 'create' -%}
        {%- elif value_uber.environment[env_item] != false and value_uber[env_item] != [] -%}
            {%- set operation_type = 'update' -%}
        {%- else -%}
            {%- set operation_type = 'cancel' -%}
        {%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
    {{- card_list.append(operation_type) -}}
{%- endfor -%}
```